# Filtering pandas df with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a pandas df:

```
df
                          DEtoDK         DKtoDE         
                            self other     self    other
2021-01-01 00:00:00+00:00    0.0   NaN  2230.08      NaN
2021-01-01 01:00:00+00:00    0.0   0.0  1887.72  2230.08
2021-01-01 02:00:00+00:00    0.0   0.0  1821.33  1887.72
2021-01-01 03:00:00+00:00    0.0   0.0  1743.20  1821.33
2021-01-01 04:00:00+00:00    0.0   0.0  1720.78  1743.20
...                          ...   ...      ...      ...
2021-05-31 19:00:00+00:00    0.0   0.0   782.88   892.16
2021-05-31 20:00:00+00:00    0.0   0.0   872.96   782.88
2021-05-31 21:00:00+00:00    0.0   0.0  1165.36   872.96
2021-05-31 22:00:00+00:00    0.0   0.0  1418.32  1165.36
2021-05-31 23:00:00+00:00    0.0   0.0  1393.28  1418.32
[3624 rows x 4 columns]
```

I would like to filter this df, with some conditions like, if the `(DEtoDK, self)` or `(DKtoDE, self)` values are 0. For that I am using the following:

```
df.loc[(df[('DEtoDK', 'self')].values == 0) | (df[('DKtoDE', 'self')].values == 0)]
```

And this works, however when the df does not have any 0 values then I was expecting to generate an empty dataframe, however I am getting a KeyError.

```
df.loc[(df[('DEtoDK', 'self')].values == 'test') | (df[('DKtoDE', 'self')].values == 'test')]
KeyError: False
```

so the conditions are generating `False`, instead of an empty array, therefore pandas cannot locate. How can I fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for `values`:

```
df.loc[(df[('DEtoDK', 'self')] == 0) | (df[('DKtoDE', 'self')] == 0)]
```

Comment: works ty! and because of the `.values` I was getting the error for `'test'`